# Verilog port width larger than defined

Tags: verilog, simulation

I simulated a design and viewed waveforms in Simvision, and an input port width is shown as `in1[223:0]`. But, it was declared as:

```
parameter BW = 13;
...
input [16*BW-1:0] in1;
```

I'm expecting it to be `in1[207:0]`.

What are any reasons the port size would be changed by the simulator in Verilog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `parameter` value can be overridden when a module is instanced inside another module.

Since `in1` is 224 bits wide, and since 224 = 16 * 14, the `BW` parameter is probably being overridden as 14 (`BW` = 14).

Refer to [How to instantiate a module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67509123/197758).